# Wordpress taxonomy and archive custom class

Tags: theme-development, filters, actions

I want to add custom class. But archive and custom taxonomy both are executed at the same time. When I want to add class to taxonomy page, the archive class is also added. I understand taxonomy is also one kind archive. But I do not want to add archive class to taxonomy. How can I add only taxonomy class?

My approach to do so

```
    function fotogruf_layout_class(){  
    if (is_search()) {
        echo $search_layout_class;
    }

    if( (is_post_type_archive('gallery')) || (taxonomy_exists('gallery_category')) ){
        echo $gallery_layout_class;
    }
    if (is_archive()) {
        echo $archive_layout_class;
    }       
}
```

Search page is working fine. But taxonomy page add class from archive class also . I do not want archive class to be added on taxonomy page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another layer of condition to your `is_archive()` test, so that your archive class is only output when the other two are NOT true:

```
function fotogruf_layout_class(){  
    if ( is_search() ) {
        echo $search_layout_class;
    }

    if ( (is_post_type_archive('gallery') ) || ( taxonomy_exists('gallery_category') ) ){
        echo $gallery_layout_class;
    }

    if ( is_archive() ) {
        if ( ( !is_post_type_archive('gallery') ) || ( !taxonomy_exists('gallery_category') ) ) {
            echo $archive_layout_class;
        }
    }       
}
```

WP's built in body classes might do this for you automatically if implemented.  Maybe not to the level of detail you are looking for, however.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/